# How does Laravel's auth system work internally?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

After authenticating a user with Laravel's `Auth::attempt($credentials);`, the `document.cookie` variable is still empty, so Laravel auth system is not cookie/session based?

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sets laravel_session cookie even before any authentication attempt and later use it for storing session variables and authentication information. It seems there is some problem with your test environment.